# "Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized" taking long time during boot

Tags: networking, drivers, bluetooth, 18.10, boot-time

**Output of dmesg:**

```
[   18.062831] wlp1s0: associated
[   18.516902] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlp1s0: link becomes ready
[   18.844430] vboxdrv: loading out-of-tree module taints kernel.
[   18.862837] vboxdrv: Found 8 processor cores
[   18.880547] vboxdrv: TSC mode is Invariant, tentative frequency 1800001178 Hz
[   18.880549] vboxdrv: Successfully loaded version 5.2.18_Ubuntu (interface 0x00290001)
[   18.903066] VBoxNetFlt: Successfully started.
[   18.925115] VBoxNetAdp: Successfully started.
[   18.959469] VBoxPciLinuxInit
[   18.975413] vboxpci: IOMMU not found (not registered)
[   72.120167] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   72.120177] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   72.120183] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[   74.132007] rfkill: input handler disabled
```

"Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized" Taking alot of time.

**Output of dmesg after removing virtualbox:**

```
[   13.302018] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp1s0: link is not ready
[   13.395355] pcieport 0000:00:1d.0: AER: Corrected error received: 0000:00:1d.0
[   13.395360] pcieport 0000:00:1d.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
[   13.395363] pcieport 0000:00:1d.0:   device [8086:9d18] error status/mask=00000001/00002000
[   13.395365] pcieport 0000:00:1d.0:    [ 0] Receiver Error         (First)
[   13.411632] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp1s0: link is not ready
[   13.852753] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp1s0: link is not ready
[   17.499926] wlp1s0: authenticate with e4:6f:13:4f:4f:c0
[   17.500332] pcieport 0000:00:1d.0: AER: Corrected error received: 0000:00:1d.0
[   17.500340] pcieport 0000:00:1d.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
[   17.500344] pcieport 0000:00:1d.0:   device [8086:9d18] error status/mask=00000001/00002000
[   17.500347] pcieport 0000:00:1d.0:    [ 0] Receiver Error         (First)
[   17.506088] wlp1s0: send auth to e4:6f:13:4f:4f:c0 (try 1/3)
[   17.508958] wlp1s0: authenticated
[   17.512158] wlp1s0: associate with e4:6f:13:4f:4f:c0 (try 1/3)
[   17.516486] wlp1s0: RX AssocResp from e4:6f:13:4f:4f:c0 (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=1)
[   17.518462] wlp1s0: associated
[   17.612677] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlp1s0: link becomes ready
[   41.905950] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   41.905961] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   41.905967] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[   43.554072] rfkill: input handler disabled
```

**Systemd-analyze:**

```
Startup finished in 3.461s (kernel) + 22.792s (userspace) = 26.253s
graphical.target reached after 22.754s in userspace
```

**Systemd-analyze blame:**

```
          13.937s plymouth-quit-wait.service
          7.473s postgresql@10-main.service
          6.502s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
          5.480s fwupd.service
          5.170s bolt.service
          4.933s mysql.service
          3.663s networkd-dispatcher.service
          3.618s ModemManager.service
          3.532s systemd-journal-flush.service
          3.092s udisks2.service
          2.637s dev-sda2.device
          2.361s motd-news.service
          2.348s accounts-daemon.service
          2.310s apparmor.service
          2.123s plymouth-read-write.service
          1.849s gpu-manager.service
          1.823s networking.service
          1.774s avahi-daemon.service
          1.732s bluetooth.service
          1.727s grub-common.service
          1.710s rsyslog.service
          1.682s apport.service
          1.643s wpa_supplicant.service
```

Acer Swift 3 Laptop 
The wifi and bluetooth adapter is Intel Wireless 7265. Driver iwlwifi.
256GB Micron 1100 SATA3 M.2 SSD.

Comment: Try removing vbox

Comment: Didn't work. (Added Dmesg output after removing Virtualbox in post).